Oracle LogMiner reconstructs Extended String value incorrectly
I have an Oracle EE 19.3 environment setup where MAX_STRING_SIZE is set to EXTENDED, supporting up to 32k length strings. In this environment, I have two very simplistic tables
CREATE TABLE test_a (id NUMERIC(9,0) primary key, DATA varchar2(4000));
CREATE TABLE test_b (id NUMERIC(9,0) primary key, DATA varchar2(32000));

The only difference here that test_a does not take advantage of extended strings while test_b does.
Now in test_a if I issue the following SQL statement:
UPDATE test_a
   SET DATA = 'I haven''t, no.'
 WHERE id = 1;

The reconstructed SQL generated by LogMiner appears as follows:
update "SCHEMA"."TEST_A" set "DATA" = 'I haven''t, no.' where "ID" = '1' and "DATA" = 'test';

If I take this reconstructed SQL use any number of SQL parsers, they successfully parse this SQL without failure as its seen generally as consistent and correctly formed.
Now in test_b if I issue the exact same SQL statement, the reconstructed SQL generated by LogMiner is:
update "SCHEMA"."TESTB_B" set "DATA" = 'I haven't, no.' where "ID" = '1';

I understand that extended strings are treated more like CLOB fields in LogMiner in this context, which is why the extra predicate for "DATA" is missing here, but that's not my concern. My concern is that the mutated value for "DATA", the value of 'I haven't, no.' is unparsable all because LogMiner fails to escape the nested apostrophe (') like it does when working with a non-extended string field.
Does anyone know if this has been reported as a known bug or is there a way to force LogMiner to correctly reconstruct the SQL so that the latter SQL mirrors the correct SQL for non-extended string fields?
UPDATE:
I should point out that all the documentation around extended strings seem to indicate that Oracle treats such VARCHAR2 fields that exceed 4000 in size like CLOB.  However while that's technically the case, it has no issue reconstructing the character data for CLOB fields and escaped the apostrophe (') correctly when the field is explicitly set as a CLOB data type. So to me, this seems like a bug in LogMiner's SQL reconstruction.

I've not been able to find a matching bug. I would contact customer support.
